# QML multimedia cannot play m3u8 that is generated with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, qml, http-live-streaming

With the following command, I am trying to stream an IP camera over web:

````
ffmpeg -re -i "rtsp://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port>" -c:v copy -c:a copy -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_list_size 5 -hls_wrap 5 -hls_time 2 -hls_flags split_by_time -segment_time_delta 1.00 -reset_timestamps 1 -hls_allow_cache 0 -movflags faststart live.m3u8```
````

This command, produces **live.m3u8** and five ts files: **live0.ts**, **live1.ts**, **live2.ts**, **live3.ts**, and **live4**. And conversion goes smoothly. At some random point, the content of live.m3u8 is as follows:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:92
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live2.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live3.ts
#EXTINF:2.035800,
live4.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live0.ts
#EXTINF:1.963278,
live1.ts
```

However, when I tried to play live.m3u8 with the following QML code, it only played a very first segments of it:

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Window
{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Item
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        MediaPlayer
        {
            id: mediaplayer
            source: "path-to-live/live.m3u8"
            videoOutput: videoOutput
        }

        VideoOutput
        {
            id: videoOutput
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: mediaplayer.play();
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is: I manually deleted live.m3u8, and obviously, ffmpeg generated another one after! Then I clicked on the QML program window, and surprisingly, it played the stream nonstop as it was expected at the first run!

What is the problem here? What I am missing? Should I change the ffmpeg command or do something with my qml code? Any idea or help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `live.m3u8` to work at all, but, I suspect your issue is the `m3u8` is being read at load time, not at the time your `MouseArea` is pressed. This means that the information in the `m3u8` could be stale if you're regenerating `live.m3u8` whilst your program is running, it would not pick up changes. In order to pick up the most latest changes of `live.m3u8` you should consider assigning `mediaplayer.source` as late as possible, e.g. at the time of `MouseArea` click.

```
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                mediaplayer.source = "";
                mediaplayer.source = "file-url-to-live/live.m3u8";
                mediaplayer.play();
            }
        }
```

Also, since you have `ffmpeg`, you can transcode to anything you want, so, why don't you transcode it to a single file that you know that Qt can play? For me, the following works on my Windows machine (i.e. I am forcing `mp3` audio codec, `mpeg4` video codec, and an `avi` file format container).

```
ffmpeg -y -i ... -c:v mpeg4 -c:a lipbmp3lame live.avi
```

Another choice would be to use mpeg (e.g. `mp3` audio with `mpeg1 video` at 25 fps in a `mpg` file format container). This would be a better choice if you are unable to use `avi`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i ... -c:v mpeg1video -c:a lipbmp3lame -r 25 live.mpg
```

Even though you have Qt5.15.x imports it looks like you are using Qt6-style multimedia.

In Qt5.15.x, the documented usage of `VideoOutput` is that `VideoOutput` refers to `MediaPlayer`, not the other way around. The UI/UX is in the `VideoOutput` you can place `MediaPlayer` anywhere and as a top-level component. It serves no purpose placing it inside an `Item`. In fact, there is actually no need for the `Item` component in your example, so, I've refactored it:

```
// Qt5.15.x version
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15
Window
{
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    MediaPlayer
    {
        id: mediaplayer
    }
    VideoOutput
    {
        id: videoOutput
        source: mediaplayer
        anchors.fill: parent
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                mediaplayer.source = "";
                mediaplayer.source = "file:///C:/Temp/Vid/live.avi";
                mediaplayer.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Qt6, there is no need to supply version numbers to your imports, so your original code stands. However, my comment about `Item` not being necessary also stands:

```
// Qt6 version
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtMultimedia
Window {
    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaPlayer
        videoOutput: videoOutput
    }
    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                mediaplayer.source = "";
                mediaplayer.source = "file:///C:/Temp/Vid/live.avi";
                mediaplayer.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html

Comment: First of all, I thank you for the answer. 

In fact, it is required the camera to be on and working for a long time, as well as online streaming. One possible option is to use HLS to just record and keep the recent segments. So, I can't use other muxers, such as the one you've pointed out. 

For the QML side, yes, you are right. I changed the style to Qt Qt5.15.x. However, it did not help. Even I tried using Qt6. It did not help either! :(

Even I tried `ffplay`  and `VLC` to see if something wrong with the QML side. They also did play **only very first** segments.